# Converting HTML to MediaWiki .txt format not working in OpenOffice?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, html, mediawiki

I been trying to convert my HTML file to MediaWiki format by exporting it  using OpenOffice. I keep getting this error message though:

`Error saving the document <filename>:`
`Write Error.`
`The file could not be written.`

Comment: what directory are you trying to save it to?

Comment: My desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of OpenOffice?

Does it require any addons/plugins to export to the mediawiki format?

Since I read a forum post [where someone had the same problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/322225) and he updated everything where this function depends on and it solved his problem. Furthermore, it sounds like it's a known issue, have this only come up recently or did you never try it before?

Keep us posted!

Comment: I have OpenOffice 3.0. On Wikipedia it said that this feature has been supported since version 2.x (I can't remember the exact number).

Comment: I never tried it before, but it does look like a know issue. I also tried performing this a root with no luck.

Comment: I just tried it in Windows and it worked. Thanks!